# Regex to check if field has both numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I was just looking for a regex expression to check and see if both numbers and letters exist.

Just to clarify the query, the regex is going to be written in javascript and used to validate an address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576196/regular-expression-allow-letters-numbers-and-spaces-with-at-least-one-letter

Comment: By number, do you mean any code point that is a single decimal digit, or do you mean numbers in full, like ∛−37 or 6.02e23 or 6.02྾10²³ or π?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression which matches any letter followed by any digit (with any possible characters in between) or digit then letter (with anything in between):

```
var hasNumbersAndLetters = function(str) {
  var regex = /(?:[A-Za-z].*?\d|\d.*?[A-Za-z])/;
  return !!str.match(regex);
};
```

Comment: A-Z is always the wrong way to talk about letters.  Welcome to Unicode.

Comment: @tchrist: so true, quick'n'dirty out of habit; how would you match any letter in any supported language with Unicode in a regex though?

Comment: @mearics: I don't know what any suppported language means: I only use languages with Unicode support.

Comment: Why wouldn't you `return regex.test(str)`?

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to run two checks.

```
/\pL/ && /\pN/
```

To do both checks in one pattern, you need something like

```
/\pL.*\pN|\pN.*\pL/s
```

Languages supporting zero-width lookaheads can eliminate the redundancy:

```
/^(?=.*\pL/)(?=.*\pN/)/s    ( or /^(?=.*\pL/).*\pN/s )
```

But it's harder to read.

Pardon me for not using JS's match function, but the question is really about regular expressions, and I'm not familiar with JS's match function.

Comment: But javascript has no Unicode support, except for matching single characters http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @James Kyburz, I think you mean its regex engine doesn't support Unicode properties. If so, that's very unfortunate because the OP will have to do a lot of extra work. Consider for a second that 22% of Canadians live in Québec. I disupute @BIlly Moon's claim that's it's common sense to barf on those addresses.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a single word you are matching without spaces, with both numbers and letters, it can be assumed they touch somewhere - so if it matches letter then number or number then letter we have a match - so:

`([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])`

---

Edit: where there may be spaces then you can use lookahead assertions like this

```
([a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9])|[0-9](?=.*[a-zA-Z]))
```

Comment: I'm looking to validate an address or atleast somewhat validate it

Comment: With a small modification you can do letters with a number anywhere later, or a number with a letter anywhere later (using lookaheads) like this: `([a-zA-Z](?=[0-9])|[0-9](?=[a-zA-Z]))`

Comment: @Dave, Addresses are not limited to letters and numbers. "St. John's, NL", for example. Don't forget the village of "[St-Louis-du-Ha! Ha!](http://www.adaelis.com/misc/temp/xmas2004/xmas2004-005.jpg), Québec".

Comment: @BIlly Moon, That should be `(?=.*...)`, not `(?=...)`.

Comment: @ikegami is correct: you cannot use [a-z] to mean letters anymore.  It has a *code smell*.  A-Z means A-Z; **it does not mean letters!**  Only `\pL` means letters.  As for numbers, it depends what you mean.  If you mean 0-9 only, then write that; if you mean other numbers, then do not.

Comment: Madness - he wants to match an address - I don't know anybody who lives at house number π on maths street or any other kind of number than [0-9]. As for using \pL - that is a nice idea for a brave new world, but he wants to use javascript, and it simply won't work with \pL instead of [a-zA-Z]. I favor a bit of common sense mixed in with the standards police - otherwise we can lose sight of the objective!

Answer (score 0):

Saw you wanted to validate an address

Removed by regex answer as javascript has no Unicode support, except for matching single characters http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Does Javascript’s `\w` include `\pL` in it per [The Unicode Standard’s requirement](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties), or does it not?  If it does not, you will have to write that more laboriously.  Also, you should use the Unicode `Dash` property to specify all dashy code points.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
^[\w]*[^\W_][\w]*$
```

Comment: This matches 'a' (which should fail) and fails to match '@a1' (which should pass).