# iOS regex with good characters

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

In my app, i would like to only accept `NSStrings` that only consist of the following characters:

> - a-z
> - 0-9
> - A-Z
> - space (dec: 32)

What is the `NSRegularExpression` to recognize that?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Zoli

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/576206/973680

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
-(BOOL) NSStringIsValid:(NSString *)checkString
{
   NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z ]*";

   NSPredicate *stringTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stricterFilterString];
   return [stringTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

It will return YES if it is valid else NO.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*"
                                              options:...
                                                error:...];
```

If you want at least one character, use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: How to use it in `UITextField` delegate ?

Comment: `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters;`

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with regular expressions on iOS but according to the documentation, the following should work

> [a-z0-9A-Z ]+

Answer (score 1):

As per your given details:

> only accept NSStrings that only consist of the following characters:

I would like you to try this regex:

```
^[a-z\\d\\s]*$
```

It involves `^` (ensure to match from beginning of string) and `$` (ensures to match TILL the end of the string)

Check out this snippet:

```
NSString *sample = @"df$hjkds hfkshf 9397 AZZ";//@"dfhjkds hfkshf 9397 AZZ";
NSError  *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[a-z\\d\\s]*$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:sample
                                  options:NSMatchingReportProgress
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [sample length])];

// Print matches (if any) -- Optional
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
    NSLog(@"%@",[sample substringWithRange:match.range]);

// Acknowledge if no matches found -- Optional
if([matches count] == 0)
    NSLog(@"No matches found");
```

Please note that, the usage of `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` in `option` will not take overhead of matching Uppercase letters (A-Z).

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Zoltan Varadi, have you checked my solution ?

Comment: nice answer it works fine. Is there any way to check only 2 digits and 2 letters atleast in string

Comment: @CharanGiri, glad to see its useful for you. You might looking at this regex: `^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{4}.*)$` check out demo here :http://rubular.com/r/Ua2qe8j4eC. This will match string having atleast two alpha and numeric chars and may be something else as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer but in few cases it's not working ex"12@1wsasd"... this is what i used and working good (?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){2})(?!.*[\\s])^.*$